# Is this PHP code XSS proof?

Tags: php, xss

Is the following PHP code XSS proof?

```
<?php

$site = $_GET["url"];

echo "<a href='".str_replace(array("\"", "'", "javascript:", "vbscript:"), array("%22", "%27", "", ""), $site)."'>Site</a>";

?>
```

Comment: You should use the php function htmlentities() to prevent XSS.

Comment: Your method does not work in this case. Be aware!

Comment: Writing filters like this is pretty dangerous, because there are a lot of gotcha cases.  Find a good HTML escaping library and use it.

Comment: @BaileyS Now I can see =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not.

Try insert `javascript&colon;alert(9)` as the URL, or like @wireghoul pointed, `JAVASCRIPT:alert(9)`. Even with `javascript :alert(9)` in older browsers (IE < 8, I guess).

Better solution:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');

$site = $_GET["url"];
$site_lowercase = strtolower($site);

if(strpos($site_lowercase, "http://")===0 || strpos($site_lowercase, "https://")===0){
    $possible_xss = false;
}
else if(strpos($site_lowercase, "ftp://")===0 || strpos($site_lowercase, "ftps://")===0){
    $possible_xss = false;
}
else if(strpos($site, "/")===0){
    $possible_xss = false;
}
else{
    $possible_xss = true;
}

$site = str_replace(array("\"", "'"), array("%22", "%27"), $site);

echo "<a href='".(($possible_xss)?"//".$site:$site)."'>Site</a>";

?>
```

Comment: @Rook Your payloads do not work, because my code changes ' for %27. Are you sure? Please try it in writecodeonline.com.

Comment: @Rook I tested my code a lot, and I can not see how it is exploitable.

Comment: I ran it on writecodeonline.com using ```$site="JAVASCRIPT:alert(1)";```. I would recommend using a whitelist to ensure no malicious data is included in the output.

Comment: @wireghoul Your payload does not works in my code.

Comment: URLs are case sensitive.

Comment: @Lucas NN Sorry I had trouble reading the code formatting in an previous revision.  The only attacks I'm aware of would require the page to specify an alternative character set,  such as GBK which permits multi-byte character consumption.

Comment: @Gumbo is right,  this filter won't work for youtube links https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZTXYCJk05w

Comment: Just add `target="_blank"`, and problem solved. Even if there's run-able code, it won't be executed /on the current page/ as it opens a new tab / window.

Comment: Not that you could store the lowercase variant in a separate variable or use `stripos` instead …

Comment: @AcidShout XSS in that context could still be used for phishing.  An attacker could build a fake login page using `document.write()`.

Answer (score 17):

I'm generally a fan of not re inventing the wheel because people way smarter than us already did. I did a quick search for you and found the current library you can use: https://code.google.com/p/php-antixss/

Re: your code,  it looks a little too simple to prevent fully. I would use a standardized solution that is used by others and continuously contributed to as new exploits develop.

Hope it helps.

Comment: _"people way smarter than us"_ how do you know?

Comment: I would probably say `people who put time and effort into this matter already` instead.

Answer (score 1):

There's a ton of ink written on the subject of why you shouldn't try doing your own homebrew filters for these things! Please have a look at [OWASP's XSS mitigation guidelines](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Use the proper libraries for these things - [OWASP ESAPI for PHP](https://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-php/) is a great tool to start with. I'd look at [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) as well.